# Performances with many fields per content type

Tags: 7, entities, performance

Drupal creates a new table for every new field in a content type.

How much this affects the performance in fetching data when the fields of an entity are 15 or more?

Is possible to store all fields in a table (with a new entity?) without drawbacks? Is worthwhile?

Comment: I rectify, Drupal creates two new tables for a new field if we consider the revision table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL limits you to [61 table joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/joins-limits.html) but Drupal doesn't care about this limit. Each field gets loaded individually, so every field will slow down Drupal a little bit but there is no practical limit. The impact depends on how long a round trip to the database takes. If you have Apache & MySQL on the same box and you're using sockets for communication then the impact will be minimal (read [slides 60-68 from my presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1AgnurTWsWdMAFjfFmSU7mk2zfJu8jG_KmVdZ7-o6Pok/edit#slide=id.g385c64257_0182) for more info). If Apache & MySQL are on different servers then the number of fields will have more of an effect. All of this can be mitigated by using something like the https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache module.

Comment: why drupal doesn't take advantage of using a join? Your presentation is very helpful.

Comment: It's hard to do joins with fields that contain multiple values. If you have 3 fields with 3 values you'll get 9 rows back if using joins. Only in MySQL can you work around this by using group by with group concat & concat; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826196/multiple-grouping-in-mysql-queries-group-concat-group-by-inner-joins-where-a I use this technique in the apdqc module for session reading http://cgit.drupalcode.org/apdqc/tree/apdqc.session.inc#n86

Comment: Just a last question. I've understand that the number of fields isn't a significant issue , but I wonder anyway if is possible to create an entity with all fields stored in a single table without losing the Drupal functionalities on a such entity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could do it (heck you can do just about anything), but it would be a custom module. Personally I would not do it as it would cause more trouble than it's worth. A famous quote says that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". If the number of fields do become an issue you can use the field storage engine inside of the [mongoDB module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb).